# OR-Tools MIP Python wrapper: is there a way to introduce products (e.g. coef * x * y < threshold) into objective and constraints

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, or-tools

My MIP problem requires semi-continuous variables : 
Problem formulation states that all goods could be either produced at Minimum Order Quantity (MOQ) or as 0, which could be summarized as: 
X<sub>i</sub> >= MOQ<sub>i</sub> or  X<sub>i</sub> = 0, 
where  X<sub>i</sub> is a decision variable for the amount of *"i"* goods to be produced.

This is typically solved by introducing a binary variable Y<sub>i</sub> which can only take values 1 and 0: 
X = solver.NumVar(lbound= MOQ, ubound = 'infinity', name = 'X<sub>i</sub>')
Y = solver.IntVar(lbound = 0, ubound = 1, name = 'Y<sub>i</sub>')
That combination of variables is then used in all constraints and objective function:
 as a product. 
(e.g. X<sub>1</sub>*Y<sub>1</sub> + ... +  X<sub>i</sub>*Y<sub>i</sub> <= 1000) 
Another option is to make X<sub>i</sub> semi-continuous, able to have values 0 or >=MOQ

I couldn't find a way to implement any of those options in current OR-Tools python wrapper.
The rest of the problem (production planning) is nicely expressed as a linear problem (with option to make some of the variables Integer) and I would ideally like to have MOQ also be a parameter that could be turned on/off.

Could anyone give any suggestions on how to achieve that? May be recommend another instrument?

I obviuosly tried to just do products anyway:

```html
x = solver.NumVar(0.0, infinity, 'x')
y = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'y')

solver.Add(5 * x * y <= 170.5)
```

And got:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver_natural_api.py in **init**(self, expr, coef) 
177       self.__coef = coef 
178     else: 
--> 179       raise TypeError 
180 
181   def **str**(self):

TypeError:

Comment: You essentially have a bool var and a non-negative continuous variable whose product you want to linearize (if I understood correctly). [This](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable) seems relevant.

Comment: @watchdogs132, thank you yes, that is exactly my question and an answer to it!

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, if your problem is integral, CP-SAT supports complex domains natively.

```
x = model.NewIntVarFromDomain(cp_model.Domain.FromIntervals([0, 0], [5, 100]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the sugesstion! I've also already considered that option, but considering that i have a MIP problem, not so convenient in my case